# QUnit testing: how to test the response of an Ajax call within a method?

Tags: ajax, qunit

so I want to test a method called 'getTheValues', which makes an Ajax call. I've mocked the server response with the values but when I run the test I get two failures but no explanation of why they failed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
test("Test - call Ajax within method.", function () {
var callback = sandbox.spy();
server.respondWith("GET", "/ajaxtest/getmethod",
                   [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    '[{ "id": 123, "name": "John" }]']);

getTheValues();
server.respond();

ok(callback.calledOnce, "Callback was called once");
ok(callback.calledWith([{ id: 123, name: "John" }]), "Callback with correct values.");
});

function getTheValues(callback) {
// do some stuff including an ajax call:

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: '/ajaxtest/getmethod',
    success: function(data) {
    }    });
}
```

Comment: We'd probably need to know what the failures say before we can help... what does qunit give you back? Just looking at the code, I'd assume that the `success` handler calls something called `sandbox`? Honestly not sure.

Answer (score 0):

first the (working) code:

```
QUnit.module('Test Module', {
  before: function () {
    this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  },
  after: function () {
    this.server.restore();
    delete this.server;
  }
});

QUnit.test("Test - call Ajax within method.", function (assert) {
  var callback = sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
  this.server.respondWith("GET", "/ajaxtest/getmethod", /*?id=123&name=-John*/
    [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      '[{ "id": 123, "name": "John" }]']);

  var a = getTheValues();
  this.server.respond();

  assert.ok(callback.calledOnce, "Callback was called once");
  var callArgs = callback.args[0][0];
  assert.equal(JSON.stringify(callArgs.data), JSON.stringify({ "id": 123, "name": "John" }));
});


function getTheValues() {
  // do some stuff including an ajax call:

  $.ajax({
    data: { id: 123, name: "John" },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: '/ajaxtest/getmethod',
    success: function (data) {
    }
  });
```

next explanations

1. this seems to me this is not pure QUnit test. I assume you're using SinonJS as well.
2. on the spy method you need to point what will be spied

   sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax")
3. you cannot use callback.calledWith like this for it returns true/false and comparing objects ({}==={}) will (almost) always return false. So this test will constantly fail. Instead you need spy arguments (in your case callback.args[0][0];) and compare particular part with desired result. More about this you could [find here](http://legacy.sinonjs.org/qunit/)
   Actually you do not need to extract those but I did it to make code (hopefully) more clear.

So

- 1st extract arguments,
- next strignify objects to be comparable
  without any other code and
- then use equal method to compare with
  expected values

And finally your mock object lacks data object with will be send along with the GET request.

HTH